# postgresql подскажите как создать сжатый TOAST столбец?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица с BATEA полем, в котором сжаты данные, xml файлы, Для экономии места. Тоесть выборка, их расжимаем и выдаем.

Но узнали что вроде как есть какой то TOAST тип поля, можно хранить данные в открытом виде, а postgres сам позаботиться об их сжатии.

Вот https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/storage-toast.html

Подскажите как это создается? Так и не нашел примера, не могу понять как создать обычный текстовый столбец, но сжатый

```
CREATE TABLE "table" (
    "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "txt" TEXT TOAST ??????? , 
    PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TOAST` это не тип данных. Вообще фактически это костыль. На нижнем уровне данные строки размещаются в 8кб блоках - страницах (в принципе, не обязательно 8кб, это опция времени компиляции - но ни разу не видел, чтобы её меняли). И строка данных целиком не может быть больше 8кб размером. Вообще не может, это hard-лимит. Но если пользователь хочет сохранить что-нибудь побольше - он может это сделать. При этом данные прозрачно для пользователя нарезаются на части и хранятся в отдельных служебных `toast`-таблицах. Попутно могут пытаться сжиматься - насколько помню, алгоритм сжатия там используется быстрый и не слишком хорошо сжимающий.

Это происходит полностью автоматически, единственная доступная настройка - возможно выбрать [одну из 4 стратегий](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html#STORAGE-TOAST-ONDISK) через `ALTER TABLE SET STORAGE`:

- `PLAIN` запрещает компрессию и вынос в `toast`
- `EXTENDED` разрешает и компрессию и вынос в `toast` таблицу
- `EXTERNAL` запрещает сжатие, но разрешает хранить отдельно
- `MAIN` разрешает сжатие, хранение данных отдельно от строки будет использовано только если ничего другого не помогает

Отдельно замечу, что нет настройки, *требующей* сжимать данные либо выносить в toast таблицу. Небольшие по объёму данные не будут ни сжиматься ни выноситься отдельно.

Насколько знаю, в `toast` могут выноситься все типы данных переменной длины: text, varchar, массивы, json, jsonb, xml, hstore и другие. Реализация типов данных на C знает про использование `toast`, поэтому не могу утверждать что `toast` используется для всех типов данных переменной длины, но как минимум для большинства - точно.

То есть если у вас используется bytea больше 2кб размером - у вас уже есть и используется toast. Будет ли родной алгоритм компрессии компактнее используемого сейчас у вас - сомневаюсь, но можете проверить экспериментально.